# How can I insert values into a MySQL table which contain whitespaces

Tags: mysql, insert, whitespace

I am trying to create a large number of new records based around values which often contain whitespaces. When I run my query without any values with whitespaces it works fine.

I am running this query directly in MySQL workbench, rather than via php or other.

**My code:**

```
INSERT INTO my_table (`country`) 
VALUES 
(‘Benin’),
(‘Bolivia’),
(‘Botswana’),
(‘Burkina Faso’)
```

This returns the error:

> Error Code 1064: Syntax error... check near "Faso"

i.e. it has a problem with the space.

**What I have tried:**

Replacing all the apostrophe like characters with all the other apostophe like characters (I'm sorry, I don't know the technical names for them all) but I have used:

```
''  "" `` ‘’
```

I have also tried to escpape the whitespace but that hasn't worked

Comment: `"Burkina Faso"` or `'Burkina Faso'` should do just fine

Comment: What is the data type for the `country` field?

Comment: Thanks Ø Hanky Panky Ø, I thought I tried that but now it's working O_o that's what I get for working through the night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two different types of quotes (left and right of your values!

```
(‘Burkina Faso’)
```

do

```
('Burkina Faso')
```

instead. You can already see from the syntax highlighting on this page that your original quotes did not lead to the desired result, as string contents should be shown in a dark read colour here.

Comment: Argh, you are right, when I tried " before I was actually using “

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you :

```
INSERT INTO my_table ('country') 
VALUES ('Benin','Bolivia','Botswana','Burkina Faso')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

INSERT INTO my_table  VALUES ('Benin', 'Bolivia',
'Botswana',
'Burkina Faso')

The type of the fields should be var char or text. It should work.